# Need table details of vBulletin 4.2.2

Tags: vbulletin

Need table names used in  vBulletin 4.2.2 because i have to filter table from my project the project associated with wordpress not use prefix for any table.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the list of tables used in vbulletin 4.2.2.

```
access
action
activitystream
activitystreamtype
ad
adcriteria
adminhelp
administrator
adminlog
adminmessage
adminutil
album
albumupdate
announcement
announcementread
apiclient
apilog
apipost
attachment
attachmentcategory
attachmentcategoryuser
attachmentpermission
attachmenttype
attachmentviews
autosave
avatar
bbcode
bbcode_video
block
blockconfig
blocktype
blog
blog_attachmentlegacy
blog_category
blog_categorypermission
blog_categoryuser
blog_custom_block
blog_custom_block_parsed
blog_deletionlog
blog_editlog
blog_featured
blog_groupmembership
blog_grouppermission
blog_hash
blog_moderation
blog_moderator
blog_pinghistory
blog_rate
blog_read
blog_relationship
blog_search
blog_searchresult
blog_sitemapconf
blog_subscribeentry
blog_subscribeuser
blog_summarystats
blog_tachyentry
blog_text
blog_textparsed
blog_trackback
blog_trackbacklog
blog_user
blog_usercss
blog_usercsscache
blog_userread
blog_userstats
blog_views
blog_visitor
bookmarksite
cache
cacheevent
calendar
calendarcustomfield
calendarmoderator
calendarpermission
cms_article
cms_category
cms_grid
cms_layout
cms_layoutwidget
cms_navigation
cms_node
cms_nodecategory
cms_nodeconfig
cms_nodeinfo
cms_permissions
cms_rate
cms_sectionorder
cms_widget
cms_widgetconfig
cms_widgettype
contentpriority
contentread
contenttype
cpsession
cron
cronlog
customavatar
customprofile
customprofilepic
datastore
dbquery
deletionlog
discussion
discussionread
editlog
event
externalcache
faq
filedata
forum
forumpermission
forumprefixset
forumread
forumrunner_push_data
forumrunner_push_users
groupmessage
groupmessage_hash
groupread
holiday
humanverify
hvanswer
hvquestion
icon
imagecategory
imagecategorypermission
indexqueue
infraction
infractionban
infractiongroup
infractionlevel
ipdata
language
mailqueue
moderation
moderator
moderatorlog
navigation
notice
noticecriteria
noticedismissed
package
passwordhistory
paymentapi
paymentinfo
paymenttransaction
phrase
phrasetype
picturecomment
picturecomment_hash
picturelegacy
plugin
pm
pmreceipt
pmtext
pmthrottle
podcast
podcastitem
poll
pollvote
post
postedithistory
posthash
postlog
postparsed
postrelease
prefix
prefixpermission
prefixset
product
productcode
productdependency
profileblockprivacy
profilefield
profilefieldcategory
profilevisitor
ranks
reminder
reputation
reputationlevel
route
rssfeed
rsslog
searchcore
searchcore_text
searchgroup
searchgroup_text
searchlog
session
setting
settinggroup
sigparsed
sigpic
skimlinks
smilie
socialgroup
socialgroupcategory
socialgroupicon
socialgroupmember
spamlog
stats
strikes
style
stylevar
stylevardfn
subscribediscussion
subscribeevent
subscribeforum
subscribegroup
subscribethread
subscription
subscriptionlog
subscriptionpermission
tachyforumcounter
tachyforumpost
tachythreadcounter
tachythreadpost
tag
tagcontent
tagsearch
template
templatehistory
templatemerge
thread
threadrate
threadread
threadredirect
threadviews
upgradelog
user
useractivation
userban
userchangelog
usercss
usercsscache
userfield
usergroup
usergroupleader
usergrouprequest
userlist
usernote
userpromotion
usertextfield
usertitle
visitormessage
visitormessage_hash
```